# Coercivity of an integral operator in control theory

Tags: real-analysis, differential-equations, integration, oc.optimization-and-control

Let us consider the integral operator $T:\mathbb{R}^{n\times d}\to [0,\infty)$ such that for all $K\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times d}$,
$$
T(K)=\int_0^1 \operatorname{tr}(KK^\top \Sigma_t) \,d t,
$$
where $\Sigma$ satisfies the following matrix ​differential equation:
$$\frac{d\Sigma^K_t}{d t}=(A_t K)\Sigma^K_t+\Sigma^K_t(A_t K)^\top,
\quad t\in [0,1];\quad  \Sigma^K_0=I_d,
$$
with $A\in C([0,T];\mathbb{R}^{d\times n})$.

Is it possible to show $T(K)$ is coercive, i.e.,
$\lim_{\|K\|\to \infty}T(K)=\infty$?

---

If $n=d=1$ and $A$ is time-independent, then
a direct computation shows that $T(K)=\int_0^1 K^2e^{2AKt}dt$. By discussing the cases with $A=0$ or not, one can show $T(K)$  tends to infinity if $|K|\to \infty$.

However, I am not sure whether this argument can be extended to a general setting.

The operator arises from the optimal control of a linear ODE. Roughly speaking, you can view $K$ as the control policy and $\Sigma^K$ as the square of the state process.